# Django 1.7 filter horizontal not working for foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I have a model for shows that I want to add filter horizontal to the movie and venue fields.

```
class Show(models.Model):

    MOVIE_TYPES = (
        ('2', '2D'),
        ('3', '3D'),
    )

    CINEMAS = (
        ('C1', 'Cinema 1'),
        ('C2', 'Cinema 2'),
        ('C3', 'Cinema 3'),
        ('C4', 'Cinema 4'),
    )

    movie = models.ForeignKey('Movie', related_name='shows')
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    old_details = models.TextField(blank=True, editable=False,)
    starts = models.DateField(db_index=True,)
    starts_time = models.TimeField(db_index=True,)
    couple_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    vip = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cinema = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=CINEMAS,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, )
    booking_url = models.URLField(blank=True, )
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, db_index=True,)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, db_index=True,)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    new_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    movie_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=MOVIE_TYPES,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

In the admin I've set it up like this but when I run `python2.7 manage.py migrate movies` and restart the server it still displays like a dropdown list.

```
class ShowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['movie','venue','starts', 'starts_time','active']
    search_fields = ['movie__name','venue__name' ]
    list_filter = ['venue', 'created']
    filter_horizontal = ('venue','movie')
```

UPDATE

I edit the list_filter to `list_filter = ['created']` did a migrate and restarted the server and the changes took effect I don't think it's a migration issue. Note: I upgraded from Django 1.5 to 1.7 also.

Comment: Is `ShowAdmin` registered properly? Does everything else display as expected?

Comment: Everything shows correctly @MikeCovington I edited the showadmin to include filter_horizontal but it doesn't work.

Comment: Weird. Does `filter_vertical` work?

Comment: @MikeCovington no it doesn't I checked the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/ they only mention manytomany field maybe because it's a foreignkey and you can only select one that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter_horizontal` and `filter_vertical` options are for many-to-many fields. You can't use them for foreign keys.

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) for the options only mention many to many fields, and if you [look at the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9dcfecb7c6c8285630ad271888a9ec4ba9140e3a/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L230), you can see that the widget is only used for many-to-many form fields.

Comment: is there an alternative for ForeignKey?

Comment: No, Django does not have an equivalent of `filter_horizontal` for foreign keys. You could explore autocomplete widgets for foreign keys, to see if one meets your needs.